# Some files returning Error 520

Tags: php, .htaccess, http-error

Some of my files in my web server is returning `Error 520: Web server is returning an unknown error`. As far as I know, the files returning the errors are `index.php` and `google0f3d9b***.html` (used to verify Google Webmaster Console).

Below is my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteBase /

# Force non-www version
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.yikjin\.ga [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://yikjin.ga/$1 [L,R=301]

# Prevent 000webhost ads from poping up
php_value auto_append_file none

# Prevent directory listing
Options -Indexes

# Make index.php default
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

and my `index.php`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- ... -->
</head>

<body>
<header>
    <img src="/drawable/images/me.jpg" width="6%" alt="That's us!" title="That's us!">
    <span>Welcome to Cards!</span>
</header>

<div id="login">
    <img src="/drawable/images/cards.jpg" alt width="40%" height="auto">
    <h2 id="welcome">Welcome back,<br/>
        <span id="user">user</span>
    </h2>
    <h4>Please re-enter your password</h4>
    <form method="post">
        <label for="userid">Username</label>
        <br/>
        <input type="text" title="What's your username?
   eg. johntan" id="userid" name="userid" required>
        <br/>
        <span id="user-err"></span>
        <br/>
        <label for="pass">Password</label>
        <br/>
        <input type="password" title="What's your password?
   eg. *****" id="pass" name="pass" required>
        <br/>
        <span id="pass-err"></span>
        <br/>
        <input type="button" value="&lsaquo; Back" onclick="javascript:window.history.back();">
        <input type="submit" value="Continue &rsaquo;" name="login">
        <a href="#" target="_blank">Not you?</a>
    </form>
    <br/>
    <a href="/register.php">Register now</a>
</div>

    <link href="/drawable/css/design.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Begin Cookie Consent -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.cookieconsent_options = {"message":"We love cookies. So we use them. :D","dismiss":"Got it!","learnMore":"Whyyy...","link":null,"theme":"dark-bottom"};
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cookieconsent2/1.0.9/cookieconsent.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

<?php
    include("/drawable/connect.php"); /* $dbcon is from this file */

    if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
        $userid = $_POST['userid'];
        $pass = $_POST['pass'];

        $check_user = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE userid = '$userid' AND password = '$pass'";
        $user_query = mysqli_query($dbcon, $check_user);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($user_query)) {
            $_SESSION['user'] = $userid;
            header("Location: welcome.php");
        }
        else {
            echo "<script>alert('Invalid credentials supplied; please retry');</script>";
        }
    }
?>
```

I think it is a problem with my `.htaccess` file but I can't seem to figure out what. I am using 000webhost as my web server and Cloudflare. The link to my site is [yikjin.ga](http://yikjin.ga/). May I know what is causing the website not to work? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Firstly, I'm not seeing this error. I'm only seeing the `file.include` error at the bottom. Secondly, that error is from CloudFlare. Best to turn CloudFlare off when developing, which I assume you are if you're getting PHP errors... Also, your query for `$check_user` is vulnerable to MySQL injection attacks. Better to use PDO instead of `mysqli`.

Comment: The `file.include` error is because I haven't finish developing the web app yet. Could it be my internet connection cause sometimes I see `Error 522` appear for a split second before `Error 520` appear. The [images](http://yikjin.ga/drawable/images/cards.jpg) loaded fine in my Chrome browser though.

Comment: That means that Cloudflare is having trouble accessing domain, and that the connection timed out. As recommended before, first turn CloudFlare off when developing. Then turn it back on when you're finished, and you can troubleshoot CloudFlare errors from there. Another thing to note is that free web hosting comes with the cost of server uptime, which is not as reliable as it is with paid hosting. I would recommend that you switch to a paid package, and use CloudFlare there.

Answer (score 5):

As quoted from CloudFlare's Documentation:

> 520 error is essentially a “catch-all” response.

Which can be caused by the following scenarios:

- Connection resets (following a successful TCP handshake)
- Headers exceed CloudFlare’s header size limit
- Empty response from origin
- Invalid HTTP response
- HTTP response missing response headers

Source: [CloudFlare Error 520 Documentation](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200171936-Error-520-Web-server-is-returning-an-unknown-error)

> A 522 error response is returned when CloudFlare could not establish a TCP connection to the website’s origin server.

Which can be caused by the following scenarios:

- Rate limiting incoming connections from CloudFlare's IPs.
- A process on the webserver is consuming all of one or more resources at the origin.
- The domain is on a shared hosting platform where traffic or tasks for a separate domain on the same server is taking up one or more resources.
- Network connectivity issues between CloudFlare and the origin web server.

Source: [CloudFlare Error 522 Documentation](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200171906-Error-522-Connection-timed-out)

For your case, it would most probably be a server timeout or that DB CONN has a problem. You can try moving DB CONN in file rather than including it.

It's recommended that CloudFlare should be switched off when developing, so that it's easier to diagnose any problems with your site.

Comment: DB connect does not matter cause even if I remove all PHP code it still does not work, so I do not think this is the correct answer. Thanks for the detailed explanation about the errors though

Comment: Thank you! I switch off CloudFlare, and the error 522 gone. "Network connectivity issues between CloudFlare and the origin web server"

Comment: This saved me hours of messing about with our nginx server config, when really all I needed to do (in our case) was redirect on a POST.